# What may happen if you don't unsubscribe from an Observable in canActivate of a guard?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Please, see an example below

```
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';
import {map, take} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
              private router: Router) {
  }
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean {
    return this.authService.user.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(user => {
        if (!!user) {
          return true;
        }
        return this.router.createUrlTree(['/auth']);
      }));
  }
}
```

The `user` is of type `BehaviorSubject`, and it defines an authorization status of an user, that is if it is equal to an object, then an user is logged in, and not otherwise. Therefore, the guard activates `/auth` route if the user is logged in, and it redirects us otherwise.
Now, what will happen if I remove `take(1)` from the pipeline so that we do not unsubscribe as a result?

Comment: Slightly related to this question https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24195

Answer (score 4):

Nothing will happen, the same behaviour you experience will be preserved. I guess this question is angled more towards the "cost" of not unsubscribing.

Under the hood, angular adds the [first](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/first) operator to the observable, which completes the observable after emitting the first value.

This was added on this [PR](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/10412)

Answer (score 3):

I think there is nothing to worry about.
As far as I can see, every time a `canActivate` guard is run, by using `first()`, it will automatically unsubscribe from the returned observable.

[*check_guard.ts*](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/operators/check_guards.ts#L110-L131)

```js
function runCanActivate(
    futureRSS: RouterStateSnapshot, futureARS: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    moduleInjector: Injector): Observable<boolean|UrlTree> {
  const canActivate = futureARS.routeConfig ? futureARS.routeConfig.canActivate : null;
  if (!canActivate || canActivate.length === 0) return of (true);

  const canActivateObservables = canActivate.map((c: any) => {
    return defer(() => {
      const guard = getToken(c, futureARS, moduleInjector);
      let observable;
      if (isCanActivate(guard)) {
        observable = wrapIntoObservable(guard.canActivate(futureARS, futureRSS));
      } else if (isFunction<CanActivateFn>(guard)) {
        observable = wrapIntoObservable(guard(futureARS, futureRSS));
      } else {
        throw new Error('Invalid CanActivate guard');
      }
      return observable.pipe(first()); // <----------- Here!
    });
  });
  return of (canActivateObservables).pipe(prioritizedGuardValue());
}
```

Comment: It will automatically unsubscribe only if I leave `take(1)`

Comment: No, it will automatically unsubscribe regardless of the `take(1)`. With `take()`: `this.authService.user.pipe(take(1), map(), first())`. Without `take()`: `this.authService.user.pipe(map(), first())`